# Internet access through wifi - data log

Tags: wifi, connectivity

What information about a user is passed on or stored in the service provider network while a user access internet using wifi

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the internet service provider then it doesn't matter whether you're using wifi or a wired connection, these are the sorts of things that will typically be logged:

- your IP Address
- Page visited
- Overall downloaded amount
- Overall uploaded amount